# Good practice with python conditional import

Tags: python

I have a common utils named `utils.py`, which is shared across different target (dataset, for example). So, I have to define some target specific attributes, like function and variables.

I have try to do something like this

```
def setup(name):
    if ...:
        var = val
        import module
    elif ...:
        do something
```

But `from module import *` is prohibited within function.

Is there any good practice or any elegant way to do this?

Comment: Related: [Why is “import *” bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad)

Comment: The only good reason to import inside a function is to resolve a circular import. The only good reason to import conditionally is for Python version compatibility. And even then I would prefer `try:` / `except ImportError:`.

Comment: So you mean it's a design issue?